# Is there a Collect for TensorProduct?

Tags: tensors

I would like Mathematica to use the property that the TensorProduct is distributive to simplify expressions like

$A\otimes B+A\otimes C = A\otimes(B+C)$

Unfortunately neither Collect nor Simplify do the job

```
Collect[A \[TensorProduct] B + A \[TensorProduct] C, A]
```

and

```
Simplify[A \[TensorProduct] B + A \[TensorProduct] C]
```

both just return their argument. Is there a way to make Mathematica simplify such expressions?

Comment: `Block[{TensorProduct = Times}, 
  Collect[A\[TensorProduct]B + A\[TensorProduct]C, A]] /. 
 Times -> TensorProduct`?

Answer (score 3):

This is an experimental implementation of such a function:

```
tensorCollect[input_] := ReplaceRepeated[
  input,
  {
   Plus[
     summands___,
     Times[x___, TensorProduct[a___, R_, b___, S_, c___]],
     Times[y___, TensorProduct[a___, R_, b___, T_, c___]]
     ] :> Plus[summands, TensorProduct[a, R, b, Times[x, S] + Times[y, T], c]],
   Plus[
     summands___,
     Times[x___, TensorProduct[a___, R_, b___, T_, c___]],
     Times[y___, TensorProduct[a___, S_, b___, T_, c___]]
     ] :> 
    Plus[summands, TensorProduct[a, Times[x, R] + Times[y, S], b, T, c]]
   }
  ]
```

A simple test:

```
input = 2 A\[TensorProduct]B\[TensorProduct]R\[TensorProduct]S + 2 T\[TensorProduct]S + 3 A\[TensorProduct]B\[TensorProduct]T\[TensorProduct]S;
output = tensorCollect[input]
TensorExpand[output] == input
```

> 2 T \[TensorProduct] S + A \[TensorProduct] B \[TensorProduct] (2 R + 3 T) \[TensorProduct] S
>
> True

But it probably contains some bugs. This does also not attempt to collect as many terms as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so far this seems to work. I will do some more testing before accepting your answer

Comment: I find that your function only works if there are coefficients in front of the Tensorproducts. For example `tensorCollect[A \[TensorProduct] B + A \[TensorProduct] D]` does not work

Comment: @lennart Yeah, I know that it is not perfect. Yet, it might give you an idea how to proceed: You can add more and more transformation rules to improve upon `tensorCollect`.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `a___, b___, c___` in the tensorproduct? Everything seems to work just fine without them.

Comment: The triple underscore stand for a sequence of zero or more elements. `TensorProduct` does not have the attribute `Flat`, so we have to account for the possibility that there are other factors around and between there relevant factors `R`, `S`, and `T`. And most importantly, these factors have to correspond to each other. That will only take effect with long `TensorProducts`.

Answer (score 2):

This command will make it to move  the left argument out of brackets if to execute it twice:

```
Unprotect[TensorProduct];
TensorProduct /: TensorProduct [a_ , b_] + TensorProduct[ a_ , c_] := 
 TensorProduct[a, b + c] 
Protect[TensorProduct];
```

Idk why it produces an error message

> TagSetDelayed::write: Tag TensorProduct in
>   a_[TensorProduct]b_+a_[TensorProduct]c_ is Protected.

after the first execution.