# How can I simplify a symbolic tensor expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, tensors

My question is about simplifying tensor expressions. If I have

$(a+b)\otimes (c+d)$

The function `TensorExpand` gives

$a\otimes c + a\otimes d + b\otimes c + b\otimes d$

But is there a way back or at least a way to collect tensor terms by one one of the factors? That is, collecting by $a$ should give

$a\otimes (c+d) + b\otimes c + b\otimes d$

`Simplify` and `Fullsimpliy` and `TensorReduce` don't seem to do this, neither does `Collect`.

Comment: I would not call it a simplification.

Comment: @yarchik Solve it and call it whatever you like

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181449/7893 for a partial implementation